# How do I make it so it's stops after a right guess?

Tags: python

I just started learning python and for my first project I made a really simple number guessing game. When you guess the number right on your first or second try, it says "good job you guessed it.." and then continues to ask a number between one and ten untill it's your third try. How do I fix this?

This is the code:

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,10)

guess = None
count = 1
max_guesses = 3

while True:
    guess = input("Please type a number between 1-10:")


    if int(guess) < n: print ("Too low")

    elif int(guess) > n: print("Too high")


    else : print ("Good job!") 


    count += 1
    if count > max_guesses:
        print("You ran out of guesses! the number was " + str(n))
        break
```

I tried switching places and I tried putting the break earlier, but as I said, I just started learning last week and there's a gap of information.

Comment: Add another break in your else block

Answer (score 2):

As a good practice, don't put the statement for an `if` on the same line as the `if`.  Then, it would have been clear where you need to put in the `break`:

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,10)

count = 1
max_guesses = 3

while True:
    guess = int(input("Please type a number between 1-10:"))

    if guess < n:
        print ("Too low")

    elif guess > n:
        print("Too high")

    else:
        print ("Good job!") 
        break

    count += 1
    if count > max_guesses:
        print("You ran out of guesses! the number was " + str(n))
        break
```

Here's another way to organize this code that uses control paths in lieu of global variables:

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,10)

for _ in range(3):
    guess = int(input("Please type a number between 1-10:"))

    if guess < n:
        print ("Too low")

    elif guess > n:
        print ("Too high")

    else:
        print ("Good job!") 
        break
else:
    print("You ran out of guesses! the number was", n)
```

Comment: Ohh, you can use multiple breaks in a while-loop?

Comment: @bunabarendreft break just means "exit this current loop". You can have as many breaks as you want, but once a `break` statement is hit, the loop will exit.